# Separate href url for large screen and small screen Html

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive web application. For the web view I have the url as

```
<a href="#/mailbox/sent">Sent Mail</a>
```

But for the small screen I need the url as

```
<a href="#/mailbox/sent#toFocus"> Sent Mail</a>
```

'#toFocus' is appended with the url for focuzing the page to particular position on small devices. I am using the same code for small screen and large screens. If I put the same code for large screen, design got broke down. Is there is any way to put separate url for large screen & small screen separately?

Comment: just wanted to highlight that you have to use viewport width instead of normal window width... The normal width will not match the media query breakpoints as there is a inconsistency how browsers handle vertical scroll bar  16px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use javascript or jQuery for this.

Here is a solution using jQuery. use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` to get with and height of the device respectively , and use it to add link using jQuery `attr`.

```
var width = $(window).width(), height = $(window).height();
if ((width <= 1023) && (height >= 768)) {  //or specific device width 
  jQuery('a').attr('href','#/mailbox/sent#toFocus');
} else {
   jQuery('a').attr('href','#/mailbox/sent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JQuery, you can use CSS media queries to achieve this.

Something like:

```css
.mobile {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;  
  }
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#/mailbox/sent" class="desktop">Sent Mail Desktop</a>

<a href="#/mailbox/sent#toFocus" class="mobile"> Sent Mail Mobile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

run this after DOM is loaded. and use everywhere the addresses like on small width devices

```
$("a").each(function(i, v) {
  if($(window).width() > 676) {
    var chunks = $(this).href.split("#");
    chunks.pop();
    $(this).href = chunks.join("#");
  }
});
```